# Trickly transact SQL needed please: going round in circles

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have data like the following

```
Ftitle               Fvalue                         Freference
------               ----------                     ---------
filename             file1.java                     123
version              2                              123
cvstree              branch1                        123

filename             file2.java                     345
version              4                              345
cvstree              branch2                        345

filename             file1.java                     4556
version              3                              4556
cvstree              branch1                        4556


filename             file3.java                     4312
version              77                             4312
cvstree              branch2                        4312

filename             file1.java                     5616
version              1                              5616
cvstree              branch3                        5616
```

I have given a blank line above between some rows for easy readability. For various reasons, the table structure cannot be changed and the table has tons and tons of data.

Now, what i have is just the Fvalue for example file1.java . i would like to know if i can use a TSQL statement so that, in one single query, i get, for example all the distinct Freference values where the branch matches what i specify.

So, for example, if i give a query where i want matches for file1.java for branch1, then i just want the SQL to return me "Freference" 4556 and 123 .

Is this doable without looping through all "Freference" values for file.java and then further filtering it where Fvalue is branch1? This kind of loop becomes very slow.

Comment: is Freference unique to each triplet?  in other words, could any other set of rows have 4312 as Freference?

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT --DISTINCT intersect removes duplicates
   Freference
FROM
   MyTable M1
WHERE
   M1.Fvalue = 'file1.java'
INTERSECT
SELECT --DISTINCT intersect removes duplicates
   Freference
FROM
   MyTable M2
WHERE
   M2.Fvalue = 'branch1'
```

OR

```
SELECT DISTINCT
   M.Freference
FROM
   MyTable M
WHERE
   M.Fvalue = 'file1.java'
   AND
   EXISTS (SELECT * FROM 
            MyTable M2
         WHERE
           M2.Fvalue = 'branch1'
           AND
           M.Freference = M2.Freference)
```

Comment: Neither query references tables properly

Comment: Still one tiny mistake there (`MyTable M` in the first query should probably be `MyTable M1`). One other thing: INTERSECT 'returns any *distinct* values that are returned by both the query on the left and right sides of the INTERSECT operand', as per MSDN (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188055.aspx). That is, no need for explicit DISTINCT, I think.

Answer (score 3):

INTERSECT is an option
But a direct join has better support across DBMS.

```
select distinct a.freference
from tbl a
inner join tbl b on a.freference = b.freference and b.fvalue = 'branch1'
where a.fvalue = 'file1.java'
```

Comment: @gbn This works. It is not meant to be a common key, it is meant only to subset the first resultset.

Comment: yeah, I'm second guessing myself

Comment: As a matter of taste, I would place both filters in one clause, most probably in WHERE. They seem to be at home there.

Answer (score 2):

You just want to join the table on itself, it's pretty easy.

Edit: How about this?

```
select a.Freference 

from table a inner join table b
        on a.Freference = b.Freference
        and a.Ftitle = 'filename'
        and b.Ftitle = 'cvstree'
where 
    a.Fvalue ='file1.java'
    and b.Fvalue = 'branch1'
```

Answer (score 1):

```
select * 
from theTable 
where Ftitle = 'file1.java' 
and Fvalue = 'branch1'
```

Comment: Ftitle is never file1.java. So you'll get zero rows back

Comment: "Ftitle" has nothing to do with it

Answer (score 0):

> is Freference unique to each triplet?
>   in other words, could any other set of
>   rows have 4312 as Freference?

Yes, Freference is unique to each triplet. Sorry if i didn't mention that before. I am trying out the various ideas here in the meantime